# c# scoping issue, simple fix i'm sure

Tags: c#, scoping

So I have the following code, and It works nearly flawlessly, except for the fact that no matter what I do I cannot get the parts that are like: `for (int.parse(txtGuess.Text) == numbGen)` it will not recognize 'numbGen' no matter where I place it in the code. I cannot place it inside the button click function because I don't want the number to change, unless they've gotten it correct or re-opened the form.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;


    namespace WindowsApplication1
    {
        public partial class rndNum : Form
        {
            public rndNum()
            {
            }

            private void rndNum_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                int numbGen = RandMake(0, 100);
            }

            private void txtGuess_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }

            private void btnEval_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                int guesses = 0;
                while (txtGuess.Text != "")
                {
                    if (int.Parse(txtGuess.Text) == numbGen)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("You got it!", "Congratulations!");
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (int.Parse(txtGuess.Text) > numbGen)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Sorry, but you're too high. The number was " + numbGen + "!", "Please try again.");
                        txtGuess.Clear();
                        txtGuess.Focus();
                        guesses++;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (int.Parse(txtGuess.Text) < numbGen)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Sorry, but you're too low. The number was " + numbGen + "!", "Please try again.");
                        txtGuess.Clear();
                        txtGuess.Focus();
                        guesses++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }



            private static int RandMake(int min, int max)
            {
                Random mkRnd = new Random();
                return mkRnd.Next(min, max);
            }
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean exactly by `and It works nearly flawlessly, except for the fact that no matter what I do I cannot get the parts that are like: for (int.parse(txtGuess.Text) == numbGen) it will not recognize 'numbGen' no matter where I place it in the code. I cannot place it inside the button click function because I don't want the number to change` ???

Comment: Shouldn't the guesses variable be form level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`numbGen` must be a class member.

Change

```
        private void rndNum_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int numbGen = RandMake(0, 100);
        }
```

to

```
        private int numbGen;
        private void rndNum_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            numbGen = RandMake(0, 100);
        }
```

actually you don't need to put the initialization in `Form.Load`, you can initialize a class member directly.

```
    public partial class rndNum : Form
    {
        private int numbGen = RandMake(0, 100);
        public rndNum()
        {
        }
```

and to further refine: if you want to make sure the values is not changed you can make it `readonly`

```
    public partial class rndNum : Form
    {
        private readonly int numbGen = RandMake(0, 100);
        public rndNum()
        {
        }
```

Comment: Well, that did get rid of all of the errors, but now instead of loading the rest of the window it loads simply a grey form with no text boxes, labels, buttons, etc

Comment: @ColbyRMeier, that is because you lost the line `InitializeComponent();` in the constructor `public rndNum() { }`

Comment: Many thanks to you all! I don't know why it was so hard for me to see something so simple... I guess I just needed a fresh pair of eyes. Thank you all so much.

Comment: @ColbyRMeier, the thank you button is called "upvote" on StackOverflow (the up arrow).

Comment: I know, but I don't have enough rep to upvote. I did flag your answer, though, as my choice.

Answer (score 2):

```
int numbGen;
private void rndNum_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    numbGen = RandMake(0, 100);
}
```

try this!!!

Answer (score 2):

The others already commented on the scoping issue you noticed. But your `RandMake` method is flawed too. You should not create an instance of `Random` for each number, but reuse the instance.

The problem here is that `new Random()` uses the time as seed, and the time only changes every few milliseconds. This means that if you call `RandMake` several times within that time interval you will get the same "random" number.

This doesn't seem to be a immediate problem because you only call it once, but you should be aware of this in the future.

Comment: In general yes, but if he only intends to use the RandMake once to initialize the form it does not matter.

Comment: Yes, I know it is no immediate problem with his current code, but it's a bug waiting to happen.

Comment: @CodeInChaos I was aware that it used time as the seed, but hadn't thought of the consequences of that. I know that it's not directly a problem in the current code, but I will definitely keep that in mind for future code. Thanks, would give upvote if I had the rep.

Answer (score 0):

When you put numbGen's declaration on the inside of a method, the number only exist in that functions scope. You have to place it outside like this:

```
        int numbGen;
        private void rndNum_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            numbGen = RandMake(0, 100);
        }
```

Comment: You are correct, but giving **exactly** same answer to get some votes isn't fair.

Comment: Code like that is trivial. When I started writing my answer, no one else had replied so if you want to accuse me of anything, it is of being slow. (Which is kind of ironical, since I first saw your comment now)